# Polygons split themselves when I zoom out

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, merge, topology

I've been having issues with polygons getting deleted and re-created in this layer, and also with polygons not merging the way I would expect. I thought I had everything fixed-- my topology check comes back clean (no gaps or overlaps) and when I fill the layer with a solid color there are no gaps-- but now my layers are behaving very strangely, and I'm worried I might not have fixed everything and I don't know what sanity check to use aside from my topology.

For instance, this polygon was originally split in two along a vertical line:
[image]

I merged it:

[image]

but sometimes when I zoom out, it looks like it is still in 2 pieces.

When I export it to a KML file and open it in Google Earth, it still seems to be in 2 pieces:

[image]

I feel like I'm pretty experienced with ArcMap but I have no idea where to start with trying to fix this!

I am using ArcGIS 10.6.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: How _exactly_ are you splitting and merging this polygon?

Comment: Do you mind to upload that polygon somewhere.

Comment: What happens if you try to select one half of the "split" polygon?

Comment: I assume you also ran a Repair Geometry on your layer.  If you add the layer into a new project from wherever it is stored does it still act strangely?  Over the years I've found every once in awhile an ArcMap project acts weirdly, as if it is caching information somewhere for its display.

Comment: @Hornbydd I'm using the cut tool in the Editor, and then merging them with the merge tool from the editor as well. It's worked fine with all the other shapefiles that I've used it.

Comment: OK, needed you to clarify that, because you could have been using some nutty sequence of geoprocessing tools. Looks like you are attempting to split a hole in a multi-part polygon. If you use the select tool and click to the right of it, does it highlight? If you click in it (not boundary) does it not highlight? If that happens then you are attempting to split a hole, there is no polygon, it's a inner ring of the much larger surrounding polygon.

Comment: @Hornbydd sorry, I forgot that the "editor" cut tool is different from the geoprocessing cut tool. Yes, everything highlights like it's supposed to. I also changed the symbology to be filled, and there are no holes.

Answer (score 1):

The zoom effect is strange, but the merge tool only combines datasets, you will get an edge between them. To remove that edge you need the dissolve tool http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm